# Can I create and set property of MVC3 partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Like Asp.Net applications where we create User control(ASCX), and declare some properties for that user control, which we can set from the parent page where we are using the user control, can we do the same thing in Partial View of MVC?
I want to create a partial view for Date picker in MVC, having its validation(enable/disable) property,a flag(display as timepicker or datepicker) and many other such customizable properties, based on which my partial view will behave accordingly.And use this partial view at different places in same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RenderAction()

You can call a controller action and pass parameters in here. The Controller action will then return a PartialView (With a model or just ViewBag Values)

```
public ActionResult DatePicker(bool DoSomething)
{
    ViewBag.Something = DoSomething;
    return PartialView("DatePicker");
}
```

and you call this

```
@Html.RenderAction("DatePicker", "ControllerName", new {DoSomething = true})
```

Comment: Ohh, I will try this and let you know, Thanks, I guess it should work.THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at Template Editor. This is a sample with a [DateTimePicker](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx).

Than you can pass a Model to your partialView for further actions in relation to the model's data.

Answer (score 0):

Create class `DatePickerParam` like this

```
    public class DatePickerParam{
       public boolean isEnabled{get;set;}
  //... some other properties
    }
```

call Partial

```
<%=Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MyDatePicker.ascx",new DatePickerParam(){ isEnabled=true})%>
```

your partial view model class is `DatePickerParam`